# Android Spinner's ArrayAdapter returns Parse.com objectid instead of username

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a spinner which dropdowns all users on my database and then you can pick one and when that happens I need 2 strings from that object. To do that I have added the parse.com users as objects. However this results in my Spinner containing the objectids instead of the username to show in the spinner.

I've been at this for hours trying to understand how I make the spinner both add as object and display a string from that object. This is the code;

```
 public class BLETestActivity extends FragmentActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private TextView out;
private ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
private String username;    Context context;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
private BluetoothDevice devicenew;
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> excluded = new ArrayList<>();

private Button mActionButton;

private ArrayList<ParseObject> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

private ArrayAdapter adapter;
final BluetoothAdapter btadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

private Spinner users;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble2);

    out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.out);

    // Getting the Bluetooth adapter
    users = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList);
    uniSpinnerSetup();
    users.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    //out.append("\nAdapter: " + btadapter);
    String device_bt = btadapter.getAddress();

    // Check for Bluetooth support in the first place
    // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
    if (btadapter == null) {
        out.append("\nBluetooth NOT supported. Aborting.");
        return;


    }


    // Starting the device discovery
   // out.append("\nStarting discovery...");
    btadapter.cancelDiscovery();
    btadapter.startDiscovery();
    //FINDER NYE ENHEDER
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()

    {

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            //Finding devices
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                devicenew = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                System.out.print(devicenew.getAddress());
                Log.d("Bluetooth", "jeg når her til");
     //           out.append("\nDevices Found:");
                if (!list.contains(devicenew.getAddress())) {
                    list.add(devicenew.getAddress());
                    Log.d("Devicenew", "adder");
                    System.out.print(devicenew.getAddress());
                    if(list != null) {
                        for(String object : list) {
                            Log.d("Object", "gennemløbes");
                            ScanBL();
                        }
                    }

                }
       //         out.append("\nFound device: " + devicenew);

         //       out.append("\nDone with discovery...");

            }
        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    // Listing devices

    currentUser.put("BT_ID", device_bt);
    currentUser.saveInBackground();
    context = getApplicationContext();

}
public void uniSpinnerSetup()
{

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("_User");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject object : list) {
                    nameList.add(object);
                    System.out.println("ADDING!");
                }

                users.setAdapter(adapter);


            } else {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });


}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Onitem", "her?");
    ParseObject theSelectedObject = (ParseObject) adapter.getItem(position);

    if(excluded.contains(theSelectedObject.getString("BT_ID"))) {
        Log.d("excluded", "removed");
        excluded.remove(theSelectedObject.getString("BT_ID"));
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), theSelectedObject.getString("username") + " er fjernet fra overvågning!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ScanBL();
    } else {
        excluded.add(theSelectedObject.getString("BT_ID"));
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Valgt " +
                theSelectedObject.getString("username") + ", " + theSelectedObject.getString("BT_ID"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ScanBL();
    }
    System.out.println(excluded);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Do nothing.
}
public void ScanBL() {
    final ParseQuery<ParseUser> queryParseUser = ParseUser.getQuery();
    queryParseUser.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> BTList, ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Parse", "we made it this far");

            if (BTList != null && arg1 == null && list != null) {
                for (ParseUser parseObject : BTList) {
                    if (parseObject.getString("BT_ID") != null) {
                        for (String string : list) {
                            if (string.equals(parseObject.getString("BT_ID")) && excluded.contains(parseObject.getString("BT_ID"))) {
                                String BTuser = parseObject.getString("BT_ID");
                                String user = parseObject.getString("username");
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Wow, " + user + " is nearby!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show();
                                //out.append("\nFound nearby device: " + user);
                                btadapter.cancelDiscovery();
                                btadapter.startDiscovery();
                                Log.d("Bluetooth", "burde parse?");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else {
                Log.d("Bluetooth", "Fejl i returnering af data: ");
            }
        }
    });
}
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mResource;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ParseObject[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mResource=resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        TextView text;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        text = (TextView) view; // assume your layout is only a textview
        ParseObject item = getItem(position);
        text.setText(item.getString("username"));
        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_new_thingy:
            //Toast.makeText(this, "ADD!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(BLETestActivity.this, MyPreferenceActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}



 }
```

And my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/out"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_below="@+id/out"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/out"
        android:dropDownSelector="#6269ff" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what does your adapter look like

Comment: updated with the adapter :)

Comment: you dont map anything over from the object to the adapter. how is the adapter going to know what to put where? you need to make a custom adapter

Comment: Well I pull objects, but I dont know how to tell the adapter to list the usernames in my spinner. Since the adapter already contains the information, how do I pull it into the spinner? onItemSelected can pull it fine, but dont know how to apply that to my spinner

Comment: please look up about custom list adapters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are adding the parse objects(so the adapter call's the toString() method) to your list not the username.

```
                for (ParseObject object : list) {
                    nameList.add(object);
                    System.out.println("ADDING!");
                }
```

should be:

```
                for (ParseObject object : list) {
                    nameList.add(object.getString("username"));
                    System.out.println("ADDING!");
                }
```

But i think you should override your ArrayAdapter's getView method to handle the parseobjects.

If you want to stick with the ArrayAdapter you can do it this way:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject>{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mResource;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ParseObject[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mResource=resource;
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ParseObject> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mResource=resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        TextView text;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        text = (TextView) view; // assume your layout is only a textview
        ParseObject item = getItem(position);
        text.setText(item.getString("username"));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getView(position,convertView,parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the object.getString, but the arrayList only takes objects, otherwise I can not get both strings from the database that I want. Ive been googling how to override the ArrayAdapters getView but I don't really understand it.. Can you help explain it? :/

Comment: Thank you for your edit Andre! It does not work, and its probably because Im applying it incorrectly. So what you do here is Override androids/javas own ArrayAdapter getView right? My XML is just a text view and a spinner

Comment: What is not working ? Can you post your complete code or exception ?

Comment: Its just still spitting out parseobjects in the spinner instead of usernames.. My code is a mess, yes, sorry. Have edited the post with full class code and xml..

Comment: You must change your adapter instance:

private MyAdapter adapter;
 adapter = new MyAdapter(
            getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList);

Comment: Ahh, I'm starting to understand better now.. But it will not accept the new instance; "MyAdapter() in MyAdapter cannot be applied to Expected Actual context and int".. not sure what it means since its still an object

Comment: Thanks! It compiles now, but crashes on this line;     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)' on a null object reference
 - line:                 view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

Comment: Have you copied the full code of the constructor ?

And change the context:

adapter = new MyAdapter(
            this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList);

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot 2 lines apparently.. Sorry :( Now it displays the name of the user on the spinner, but when u click the dropdown to see the rest of the users it still displays parseobjects :(

Comment: It works! Now to try to learn what happens.. Thank you tremendously Andre! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change you **onItemSelected** code like this.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("Onitem", "her?");
    //Change in below line
    ParseObject theSelectedObject = (ParseObject) nameList.get(position);
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Valgt " +
            theSelectedObject.getString("username") + ", " + theSelectedObject.getString("BT_ID"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    excluded.add("BT_ID");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however this doesnt change the Spinners list of objects. :(